# How to share image to twitter using twiiter cards

Tags: twitter, twitter-card

I have added the required 'Twitter card' meta tag content in my website and also validated it in the 'Twitter card validator' where it was working fine displaying the image properly.

The problem is earlier I was using,
, to share my post.

Now, how i need to modify the above code to share the image with the twitter button.

Comment: i was using the following code  <a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-count="none" data-url="xxxx"/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Twitter Card and image appears if somebody tweets the URL. So if you want the image to be shared, you will need to pre-populate the URL in the button for it to appear.

Note that this is different than attaching an image to a tweet. Attaching an image allows the image to appear in the timeline. Card/images in a card only appear in the detail view of a tweet.